# zsh + CMake: command line options not split

Tags: cmake, zsh

Consider the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18..3.21)

project(myproject)

option(USE_ASSERT "Use assertions" ON)
option(USE_DEBUG "Compile in debug mode" OFF)

message(STATUS "USE_ASSERT=${USE_ASSERT}")
message(STATUS "USE_DEBUG=${USE_DEBUG}")
```

With this, the following

```sh
cmake -Bbuild -DUSE_ASSERT=0 -DUSE_DEBUG=1
```

prints, as expected:

```
...
-- USE_ASSERT=0
-- USE_DEBUG=1
...
```

However, **on zsh**, with an intermediate variable this suddenly fails. E.g.

```sh
export CMAKE_ARGS="-DUSE_ASSERT=1 -DUSE_DEBUG=0"
cmake -Bbuild ${CMAKE_ARGS}
```

now prints

```
...
-- USE_ASSERT=1 -DUSE_DEBUG=0
-- USE_DEBUG=OFF
...
```

CMake thus fails to split the options. Why is this? How can I avoid this problem?

For completeness:

- Bash: everything works as expected.
- Zsh: fails consistently on Linux and OSx.

Comment: I ran the exact commands you ran in bash 5.0.17 and could not reproduce the behavior you observed. What shell are you using? This is not CMake's responsibility regardless.

Comment: @AlexReinking Thanks for trying. I'm running zsh. Based on your comment I tried running in bash, and indeed the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CMake.

Instead, it has to do with how your shell handles variable expansion and word-splitting. Since you are running `zsh`, not `bash`, it will not split words by default in a variable expansion. To restore this behavior for a particular argument, write `${=CMAKE_ARGS}` instead.